# Ansible playbook - permission denied

Tags: ansible, file-permissions

I am trying to run a playbook from Ansible 2.3.1.0. 
My remote machine is a RHEL7 with Python installed to /usr/bin/python.

My playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: my-test
  remote_user: myuser
  become: true
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
#Extend /opt to 1GB
  - name: Extend /opt 2048m.
    lvol:
      vg: rootvg
      lv: rootvg-opt
      size: 1024m
```

The error I receive:

```
fatal: [my-test.host.nu]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to my-test.host.nu closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1523204435.39-113929450187838/setup.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
```

The file "setup.py", created by Ansible, has permissions "700 myuser myuser" which I guess is a problem?

How can I make Ansible allow root to run the script?
I am not even sure if that is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to insall acl package into target system. many bugs with sudo can fixed by this package.

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin ACL already seems to be installed: "Package acl-2.2.51-12.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version" Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to pinpoint the problem. The setup.py file should never have been created in the home folder "/home/myuser" where root has no access.

I tried setting the environment variable TMPDIR and the variable "remote_tmp" in ansible.cfg as below.

ansible.cfg :

```
remote_tmp = /tmp/ansible-$USER
```

The problem was, I had missed to include the "[defaults]" "section header" before specifying the "remote_tmp" parameter. The below ansible.cfg file worked as expected.

ansible.cfg :

```
[defaults]
remote_tmp = /tmp/ansible-$USER
```